# Spring life-cycle when we refresh the application context

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I´ve been trying to find documentation that describe how Spring is manage internally a refresh of the application context.

```
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("portalResetWebApplicationContext.xml");
    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).refresh();
```

What I´m interested to know if what´s happens with all the beans that were instantiated before as singleton(By default).

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#refresh%28%29):

> As this is a startup method, it should destroy already created singletons if it fails, to avoid dangling resources. In other words, after invocation of that method, either all or no singletons at all should be instantiated.

So I suggest you to add a static counter to a class and see how many instances were created from each instance.

Comment: Thanks I saw the documentation, but was not clear enough "it should destroy already created singletons if it fails", what that´s means?! that only destroy the previous beans instantiated in case of fail?.

Comment: Will keep that for you to test... :)

Comment: I add static counter as you suggest, I´ll show you the result in the next answer